# Date format Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have the following code

```
var calendar = Calendar.current

let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour, .year, .minute])
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!

let startHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: cell.startDate as Date)
let startMinutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: cell.endDate as Date)

let endHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: cell.endDate as Date)
let endMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: cell.endDate as Date)

print("start hours = \(startHour) : \(startMinutes)")
print("end hours = \(endHour) : \(endMinute)")
```

So, the result has been right but in the wrong format. It prints 22:30, for instance, which is what I want, but when it comes to numbers less than 10, like 2 AM for instance, it prints 2:0 instead of 02:00. How can I solve this problem? I am trying to link dateformatter to calendar but I can't. I also tried to solve this by taking the approach below:

```
let myFormatter = DateFormatter()
myFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

print(myFormatter.string(from: cell.startDate))
print(myFormatter.string(from: cell.endDate))
```

But it is printing hours that have nothing to do with the exact hours. Have no idea why.

So, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to add the missing leading zero, however the best solution is using the `DateFormatter`. You have only one problem with the formatter - setting the correct time zone.

```
// safer than using identifiers that are not actually standardised
myFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: It is not working. It is printing hours that are 3 hours in advance of what it should be actually.

Comment: This is the date for instance written in the database : 2016-10-18T22:00:00.000Z. So, it is printing 01:00 instead of 22:00

Comment: Also, if the user creates an meeting with a time, isn't it possible to get his timezone and set it correctly for other users from the same timezone who see the meeting?

Comment: @rgoncalv You have some kind of time zone problem there. If your database contains `22:00` in UTC then parsing it with UTC and displaying it with UTC should result in "22:00".

Comment: I think I got why the 3h difference. Helsinki, where I am right now, is three hours ahead of UTC. So, how can I make it that the time doesn't change. So, if a meeting will begin 22:00 in the U.S, it will appear as 22:00 for everyone in the world, and knowing that the event is an specific city, the person will know that the timezone is different.

Comment: What surprises me is that "start hours" and "end hours" in the first piece of code prints the time right, just the text format that gets wrong. When using DateFormatter, as in the second piece of code, the time text format gets right but the time is wrong